# gx doesn't open the url and complains: netrw --No Line In Buffer--

Tags: netrw

My issue happens with the key combination `gx` in normal mode.

The problems happens in Vim, (I have also tried in NeoVim and it correctly opens the link in firefox directly).

I have a test file /tmp/go-to-stackoverflow.markdown which contains the url http://www.stackoverflow.com

When I hit `gx` while the cursor is on the link:

- it opens a new buffer window at the bottom which contains only one line with the link written in it
- it displays during a few milliseconds (I had to redo it several times to get each words) the message `netrw --No Line In Buffer--`

Any idea what might be wrong in my configuration, how to fix the issue?

I use vim 8.1 on NixOs 19.09.

Comment: possibly this bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4738

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, it is a current bug that is still open.
There is a workaround:

Add in the vimrc configuration file:

```
nnoremap gx :!xdg-open <cWORD> &<CR><CR>
```

(The original github discussion was referencing to this one below, but comments made it possible an improved version.)

```
nmap gx yiW:!xdg-open <cWORD><CR> <C-r>" & <CR><CR>
```

Comment: Im shocked if this mapping works: I would it expect it to yank the WORD, then run `xdg-open <cWORD>`, then *in normal mode* type ` <C-r>" & <CR><CR>`, and with nmap, those spaces could trigger leader mappings for me. The last half of it makes absolutely no sense. I would have written `nnoremap gx :!xdg-open <cWORD> &<CR><CR>`

Comment: I'm currently using it successfuly though and my leader key is space too. I'm gonna test your solution. I'll update the answer accordinly.

Comment: Any explanation why you removed the `<C-r>"` and the `yiW` ?

Comment: it doesnt seem to be doing anything that I can see

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have edited the answer with your solution.

Comment: In case anyone else is having trouble with `gvim` and this mapping: `nmap gx :!xdg-open <cWORD> &<CR><CR>`: My gvim wasn't opening anything with this but it worked fine in a terminal vim. It was driving me nuts. The problem turns out to be the guioption `!` (run external commands in a full terminal window instead of dumb terminal). I turned it off: `set go-=!`. Lo and behold `gx` in `gvim` started opening urls in my external web browser again. So I guess something is broken with running external commands in a terminal window?

Comment: @LeeBigelow I turned your separate answer into a comment, since it's directly related to an issue you had with the answer in here. Thanks!